# Change rig target control transform on 6 axis robot

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics, transform-orientation

In Blender I created a 6 axis robot with a control bone 'EndBone'.
Bone.000 is the root bone on which all IK locks are set. On the other bones only one IK lock is cleared so movement around one axis is possible.

When in pose mode I move the EndBone and everything is working fine. I have a 6 axis robot pivoting around the tail of Bone.006 (robot mounting flange) and moving along the axis of that same tail. All done with an IK constraint on Bone.006 with the chain length set to 6 and EndBone set as target Bone. EndBone is child of Bone.001 with keep offset set.

Now what I would like to do is move that pivoting and moving point from the Bone.006 tail to a place somewhere else. Like if there was a welding torch mounted on the robot flange.

What I have tried so far:

- Add an additional bone to EndBone and make that the IK target.
- Add a sphere mesh and use the mesh as target. Result was that Endbone sticked to the mesh and moves along the surface.
- Change the orientation of EndBone is Edit mode.
- Searched the net and YouTube and watched plenty of tutorials.

All do not give me the result I want. In addition to pics of the situation:

Working situation with no tool attached to the robot:
[image]

The situation I want with a tool, like a welding torch, attached to the robot:
[image]

EDIT > additional information for clarification:

This is what already is working (orientation robot mounting flange):
[image]

This is what I want to add for both linear and rotational movement (orientation robot tool):
[image]

EDIT2 Link to Blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X525l4qGZRk0TSidO3BSKWCU3KkYD9Dy/view?usp=sharing

Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards, Dennis

Comment: if you provide blend file, i will check it out

Comment: You have written a very detailed description, I appreciate that, but I still can't figure out what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Just added 2 gifs for additional info

Comment: Added URL to Blender file, hope you're able to help me on the right way here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in rest pose add Empty at tip (tail) of your EndBone
- IK Constraint on EndBone > Target = Empty, with Rotation enabled
- Bone Properties > Invers Kinematics > Lock XYZ

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if i understood you right, just just want to "offset" your target, right?

- remove IK controller from bone 6
- select bone 6, tab for edit mode, select its tail,  press E Z to extrude a new bone

[image]

Note : Be careful, that you really get bone6 selected - i had to click twice on its tail to get the right bone. The name should be bone7, then you got the right bone

- now add the "same" IK Target to your new bone with target end bone
- on bone7 lock these:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris for your quick reply, it's in the right direction but not completely what I wanted.